# How to trace Spring Integration flows?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-integration

It's my first time using Spring Integration. I'm working on an application that already implemented it. SI is used to intercept data from the client then treat them in the app, but the issue here is that they need to create new SI config everytime a new client is added. So my task is to make a generic config of SI to be used anytime a new client is added.

Here I'm trying to trace the SI flows, I understand how it works in the intern of SI, but from where that comes! I have no idea !

I tried [that](https://dzone.com/articles/tracing-spring-integration-flow-with-spring-cloud) but I didn't succeed, and I would like to ask of any solution or how could I find interceptors of SI (how many type of interceptors do we have in SI)?

The only thing I need right now is to find the entrence of data to SI and how they go from a config to an other?

I do not have the source to show you, but based from that how could you advice me?
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you look for [wiretap](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#channel-wiretap). It shows whole pass-through trace for a message

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your reply. I already looked for wiretap, but I didn't find it! In most configs there is smt like :
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="salaryFileInput"
                                      directory="${file.path}"
                                      scanner="recursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner"
                                      prevent-duplicates="false"
                                      auto-create-directory="true"
                                      channel="channel1">
        <int-file:nio-locker/>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: That's really strange, no element of those [link](https://javawithakash.wordpress.com/channel-interceptors/) appeared in the app

Comment: You may try adding `wiretap` to config (see link in my previous comment) and look in the log. First record in log will be the origin of message

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is `trace` in your terms? There is a `Message History` pattern: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageHistory.html. And yes, at some point you can `wire-tap` to some diagnostic endpoint or just logging.

Comment: I mean by trace, determine spring integration flows, from the entrance to thier end. Like the example in the link in my post. 
Thanks again to both of you I got some ideas to test
And welcome to any other suggestions!

Comment: The article you've mentioned (as well as 'tracing' term in general) supposes some kind of measurements but you seem to try just to figure out the _structure_ of the flows. If you really do, take a look at the [Integration Graph feature](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#integration-graph) provided by Spring Integration itself.

Comment: Thanks @Toparvion ! In my case the application uses a version less than 4.3 of SI which is required to use Integration graph, but that would be a great help to tale in consediration in future

Comment: Why doesn't wiretap functionality on the channel's support your needs?